# Dynamically return a class implementation in Python

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to get a dynamic implementation of an object to be used in another module .

It can be used as

- `get_implementation('Implementation1')` or
- `get_implementation('Implementation2')`.

The purpose is the have a maitainable code that can be easily extended - for example I could add another class called `Implementation3` and get it working without changing core functionality.

Is this a good approach or any recommendation ?

```
get_implementation(name):
   if name:
      return getattr(name)

class Base()
    def __init__(self, args1, arg2, arg3, arg4....):

class Implementation1()
    def __init__(self, *args):

class Implementation2()
    def __init__(self, *args):
```

- Is this a good approach or do I have better options ?
- This is for a Zope framework - do I need to chose any of their API that can do this perhaps ?

Comment: With Zope you can use the component registry (utilities or adapters), but that depends on your usecase.

Comment: Wondering if I should chose that or keep it simple like the above ? Zope seems to have many such features thats right . The above code has no learning curve , Zope Component Registry has a learning curve - both for me and maitainers

Comment: Yet you have to climb that curve for everything else you do in Zope. :-)

Comment: Thats right :-) But is it required for such a simple problem ? This seems rather straight forward instaed of "Registring" "Component" :o . Are there any advantages doing that one ? Even though I use Zope as much as possible I like to keep things simple . Is that incorrect when you use Frameworks ? If Zope can reduce this code then sure .

Comment: You can register additional components *in other modules* as needed; for utilities it's just a dictionary lookup, really. `getUtility(interface)` returns the right implementation.

Comment: You could mention it as an answer so I can up vote ?

Comment: Do you mean getUtility(interface) extends my functionality through the framework , so anyone could just use it like getUtility(interface,implementation) ? Which could otherwise be done by importing the appropriate module ? I.e getUtility registers it as a common utility for the Framework ? I am trying to understand what is it that this solves ?

Comment: You could just do this with just one module, but by using `getUtility()` you get a more powerful version that let's you add implementations without them all having to live in the one module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `globals()` to access global objects in your current module dynamically:

```
def get_implementation(name):
    return globals()[name]
```

but the caller could use:

```
getattr(module, name)
```

instead of

```
module.get_implementation(name)
```

instead if the name had to be dynamic.

If you are using Zope, consider registering your classes as utilities; instead of limiting your implementations to one module, you can then use `getUtility(interface)` or `getUtility(interface, name=name)` to look up implementations, where those utilities can be registered from any module or separate package later on.

Comment: I would do that from caller , thats a nice tip . Is the approach fine or is it considered hackish ? Recently everone things I am a hacker than a developer hence the question :-) I want to save hearing that as much as possible .

Comment: I upvoted you , not sure where the down vote comes from ! It looked clear and along the lines of what I require .